# summarizeColumns in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, daxstudio

I have Fact table related to three dimension tables and I have to calculate a measure

summerise = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(MAT[(Mat) Product],LCT[(Loc) Location Type],RSC[(Res) Resource], "Total",
CALCULATE(
SUMX(factTable,DIVIDE(factTable[QTY],factTable[CNV])))
)

the problem is I have multiple columns and it can't convert to scalar
can I add the three columns to the fact table by left join and calculate my measure?

any suggestion?

Comment: Hello, What are you trying to calculate ? your code returns a table. If your aim is only to create a measure, just put it inside the COUNTROWS() function, and It gives you a scalar result.

Comment: I would like to calculate total production by location and product and resource, Countrouws I use it for each columns (Mat, Loc, Res? or in the calculate function

Answer (score 1):

Hello Please Test this:

```
summerise =
SUMX (
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
        MAT[(Mat) Product],
        LCT[(Loc) Location Type],
        RSC[(Res) Resource],
        "Total", CALCULATE ( SUMX ( factTable, DIVIDE ( factTable[QTY], factTable[CNV] ) ) )
    ),
    [Total]
)
```

Version-2

```
summerise =
SUMX (
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        SUMMARIZE (
            factTable,
            MAT[(Mat) Product],
            LCT[(Loc) Location Type],
            RSC[(Res) Resource]
        ),
        "Total", CALCULATE ( SUMX ( factTable, DIVIDE ( factTable[QTY], factTable[CNV] ) ) )
    ),
    [Total]
)
```

Comment: Hello, when I put the measure in a table with the three dimensions it shows error
 summarizeColumns() and AddMissingItems() may not be used in this context

Comment: @NassimSaddiki I updated the answer with version-2. Please try it.

Comment: It provides the same result as I did it with ALLeXCEPT,
Just to clarify the dimension tables are related to fact table with one direction and there is no reationship between those tables, it's normal?

Comment: Yes! It is okay. Dimension tables are filtering only fact table.

Comment: this the sql query

  select 
 
 
 a11.MAT_COD ,
 a11.LCT_COD ,
    a11.RSC_COD,
 sum((a11.APO_PDN_QTY / CNV))  WJXBFS1
from factTable a11
 left join R_MAT a14
   on  (a11.MAT_COD = a14.MAT_COD)
left join R_LCT a on a11.LCT_COD = a.LCT_COD
left join R_RSC r on a11.RSC_COD = r.SC_COD
group by 
 a14.MAT_COD,
 a.APO_LCT_COD,
    r.APO_RSC_COD

I compare the result and it'not the same

Comment: Complex SQL with joins. It is great. I added Version-3. I hope It works. :)

Comment: when I add divide() I can't find my attributes in the fact table
 "Total", CALCULATE ( DIVIDE ( factTable[QTY], factTable[CNV] ) )

Comment: If we used the primary key in the fact table (Mat_Cod, lct_COde, Res_Code) in the filtre indeed of the attributes in the dimension it works? it seems logic? like in the sql query they used the attributes in the fact table and they filtre by dimension tables

Comment: @Nassim I checked your sql code. you are doing the same in sql by 'group by' statement. We do the same with summarize or summarize columns functions in DAX.

Comment: sorry I made a mistake , indeed in the original sql code they use attributes from fact tables in the group by statement 
group by 
       a11.APO_LCT_CODE,
 a11.APO_RSC_COD,
 a11.MAT_COD

Comment: And in the fact table those attributes are related by primary key to dimensions